ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,3) into shape (3,)
I am trying to make a N-body simulator that takes initial position and velocity and with output of position respect to time. I used create a function that produce the differential equation of velocity and acceleration, then plug it into ivp.solve.
This is just some background
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
import random

# This controls which part of the assignment we will be solving for
mode = 'galaxy'

if mode == 'solar':
    G = 6.6e-11 # N m^2/kg^2
    N_bodies = 4
    ### The following section contains the initial postions, velocities and masses for the four bodies.
    
    sun_r0 = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    sun_v0 = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    sun_M = 2e30 # kg
    
    earth_r0 = np.array([149.6e9, 0.0, 0.0]) # m
    earth_v0 = np.array([0.0, 29.8e3, 0.0]) # m/s
    earth_M = 5.97e24 # kg
    
    venus_r0 = np.array([108e9, 0.0, 0.0])
    venus_v0 = np.array([0.0, 35e3, 0.0])
    venus_M = 5e24
    
    mars_r0 = np.array([230e9, 0.0, 0.0])
    mars_v0 = np.array([0.0, 24e3, 0.0])
    mars_M = 6.4e23

    a = 1e-20

    # The end point of simulation, this is 10 years
    t_max = 31557600.0*10

    # How far out to plot our visualisation later
    vis_radius = 300e9

    #Create a vector that contains the position and velocity
    y_initial = np.array([
        [sun_r0,earth_r0,venus_r0,mars_r0],
        [sun_v0,earth_v0,venus_v0,mars_v0]
    ])
    mass = np.array([sun_M,earth_M,venus_M,mars_M])

elif mode == 'galaxy':
    G = 4.49e-18 # kpc^3/M_solar/kyear^2

    # Some constants for generating the locations of the bodies
    R = 50 # kpc
    z_scale_factor = 0.25
    N_bodies = 10
    M_bodies = 1e8 # M_solar
    rc = 1 # kpc
    a = rc/(2**(2/5)-1)**(1/2)
    t_max = 1000000
    mass = np.full(N_bodies,M_bodies)
    # How far out the visualisation should go
    vis_radius = 50
    
    #Create N initial values for position
    r_initial = np.zeros((N_bodies,3))

    #Create zero intial velocity
    v_initial = np.zeros((N_bodies,3))
    
    for i in range(0,N_bodies):
        ran_thi = random.random()
        ran_theta = random.random()
        ran_r = random.random()
        thi = 2*np.pi*ran_thi
        theta = np.arccos(1-(2*ran_theta))
        r = R*ran_r
        r_1 = r*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(thi)
        r_2 = r*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(thi)
        r_3 = 0.25*r*np.cos(theta)
        r_initial[i] = [r_1,r_2,r_3]

    #Put position and velocity intial values together
    y_initial = np.array([
        r_initial,
        v_initial
    ])

    #Link the velocity to aceleration
    
else:
  print("Invalid mode")
print(y_initial)

Here it the differential equation function. I tried broadcasting when calculating dvelocity_dt(acceleration), but keeping getting the error "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,3) into shape (3,)". I made constant G and mass into a [10,1] array but it didn't fix the issue.
#Flatten the initial value
y_initial_flat = y_initial.flatten()
t_eval_point = np.linspace(0,t_max,200)
t_span = (0,t_max)
rs, vs = y_initial_flat.reshape(y_initial.shape)
#Create a function that reshape the intial values
def get_rs_vs(y_flat):
    rs, vs = y_flat.reshape(y_initial.shape)
    return rs, vs


#Create a function that 
def dy_dt(t,y):
position , velocity = get_rs_vs(y_initial)
dvelocity_dt = np.zeros_like(velocity)

if mode == 'solar':
    dposition_dt = velocity

if mode == 'galaxy':
    G_array = np.full(N_bodies,G)
    for i in range(0,N_bodies):
        dvelocity_dt[i] = (
        dvelocity_dt[i]+
        (position - position[i])/(np.full(N_bodies,(((np.linalg.norm(position - position[i]))**2 + a**2)**(3/2)))).reshape((10,1)))
        
    #Calculate the magnitude of velocity (Part B)
    velocity = np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(dvelocity_dt)*np.linalg.norm(position))

    #Calculate v_x and v_y (Part B)
    v_x = np.zeros(N_bodies)
    v_y = np.zeros(N_bodies)
    v_n = np.zeros((N_bodies,3))
    for i in range(0,N_bodies):
        v_x[i] = np.sqrt(velocity/(1+(dvelocity_dt[i,0]**2/dvelocity_dt[i,1]**2)))
        v_y[i] = -v_x[i]*(dvelocity_dt[i,0]/dvelocity_dt[i,1])
        v_n[i] = [v_x[i],v_y[i],0]

Here is the Error
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[156], line 10
      8 G_array = np.full(N_bodies,G)
      9 for i in range(0,N_bodies):
---> 10     dvelocity_dt[i] = (
     11     dvelocity_dt[i]+
     12     (G_array*mass).reshape((10,1))*(position - position[i])/(np.full(N_bodies,(((np.linalg.norm(position - position[i]))**2 + a**2)**(3/2)))).reshape((10,1)))
     14 #Calculate the magnitude of velocity (Part B)
     15 velocity = np.sqrt(np.linalg.norm(dvelocity_dt)*np.linalg.norm(position))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (10,3) into shape (3,)

